# Family of quartics given the only two roots and an extremum

Tags: roots, quartics

How to find the family of quartics with only the two roots $2$, $10$, and one extremum $(-5,5)$? It should look like this:

[image: Graph]

I want a solution with "roots-factors", like this:

$$f(x) = a((x-x_A)(x-x_B)\ldots)$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider just the requirement for a polynomial to have the two given points on the $x$- axis. We can use $(x-2)(x-10)$.

Now consider just the extra requirement for a polynomial to have a point of zero gradient at $x=5$. Try $(x-c)(x-2)(x-10)$. Differentiate and put $x=5$ and you will find that $c$ must be $\frac{25}{2}.$

We require the point of zero gradient to be at $(5,-5)$. Substitute $x=5$ in $a(x-\frac{25}{2})(x-2)(x-10)$ and you will get the solution $g(x)=\frac{1}{45}(25-2x)(x-2)(x-10)$.

Then the quartic $f(x)-g(x)$ has roots at $2,5,10$ with the root at $5$ being repeated and so  is a multiple of $(x-2)(x-5)^2(x-10)$. Then  $$45f(x)=(A(x-5)^2+25-2x)(x-2)(x-10)).$$

All that remains for you to do is to (if possible) choose the values of the constant $A$ so that $f(x)$ has no "other" roots and no "other" points with zero gradient.

Comment: Hi. The "45f(x)=(A(x−5)2+2x−25)(x−2)(x−10)" works like a charm !, but I don't understand how you get the "1/45(2x−25)" of the g(x) ?

Comment: Since we just needed a solution to get us started I tried $(ax+b)$ times the other factors and calculated what $a,b$ had to be.

Comment: You tried “ g(x)=(ax+b)(x-2)(x-10) “ ? I know that is for a cubic, but when I do " g(5)=-5 ", I get " 15a+3b=1 ". Sorry, I'm a bit lost .... Could you please tell me the steps. Thanks.

Comment: You are right - I had a sign error.

Comment: Yes, there is just a small sign error, but it is not very important because the graph is just inverted along the x-axis, but above all, what I would like to know is how did you get "1/45(2x−25)" ? (the first term of g(x)). Thanks.

Comment: I've written it out in much more detail now. (You can do some of the steps in one go but you might find it helpful at first to do it in steps as I have now done in the answer.)

Comment: Yes..!!... I've understood with the "edited version" of your answer. It's clear and It works for me. Many Thanks !